Is there any way to export an existing Django model information into a visual form
I understand that I can create .dot files using django-extensions. I am also able to create SVGs from the .dot file using pygraphviz. However, the outputs are huge, ugly and difficult to navigate. Are there any tools that people can recommend that might include some form of filtering, auto layout etc.
